# How do the number of cores in the CPU relate to the rendering tiles?

Tags: rendering

Im not sure if this is a noob question but i was intrigued about something that i haven't thought about before. When rendering an image, its obvious to see the rendering tiles rendering away the image (the orange squares working on the tiles). But i never thought about this, do they relate to the CPU at all? like to get more rendering tiles, do i need more cores in my processor? The more cores the more orange squares? anyways thanks if anyone would know an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each thread of the CPU will render one tile. For example: if your computer's CPU has 4 cores and 8 threads, then blender will render 8 tiles simultaneously.

The number of threads used can be limited using a fixed number on the Performance section of the Properties Panel, the default is Auto-detect, which will use all of the available threads for rendering.

If you are using GPU, there will be one tile rendered per GPU. Multiple GPUs will allow you to render multiple tiles simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks man, it really helped me decide the components for my next PC build for rendering.