# Cycles is using Path-tracing-Tile instead of Sample

Tags: rendering, render-passes

I know this question as been asked many times before, but the solution, that usually helped doesn´t work for me. So I would be very happy about some assistance!

I built a scene, and when I try to render it is always using *Path Tracing Tile*....instead of *Samples*. 
I have NOT checked the Square Sample Box! But it is still rendering in Pathes...why could that be?[image]

Comment: Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/integrator.html?highlight=square%20samples

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing terms.
**The number of samples is not the number of tiles being rendered**.

8 samples will give you a very noisy image.

Read: [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

What you see as orange squares are **tiles** being rendered. By default blender doesn't render the whole image, but it splits it in tiles to maximize the resources on your computer. Your machine is using 8 [threads](http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/render/cycles/settings/performance.html) to render (two threads for each core on the CPU). The size of those tiles is determined in the performance tab:

[image]

The default settings are "auto-detect" to determine how many threads will be used for rendering, or you can choose to use a fixed number to keep some other processes in your computer with some resources.

If you render using GPU you will have as many tiles as GPUs you have installed in your machine. With olny one GPU, only one tile will be rendered at the time.

Read: [How do the number of cores in the CPU relate to the rendering tiles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111199/how-do-the-number-of-cores-in-the-cpu-relate-to-the-rendering-tiles)

Read also: [How can I render the way the render preview renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96720/how-can-i-render-the-way-the-render-preview-renders/96723#96723)

The square sample box does something completely different. It has nothing to do with the shape of the samples. When you enable "square samples" you are mulitplying the number of samples by itself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Dear cegaton, thank your for your fast and detailed response! Maybe it is a bit unclear. So my problem is, that when I choose 8 Samples for rendering, usually cycles was counting up the samples like 1/8, 2/8, 3/8 until 8/8. But now I choose 8 Samples and it is rendering 1736 pathes.

Comment: No, you are still not understanding. The **samples are not the number of tiles**.  8 samples will give you a very noisy image.  There is no such things as "Pathes". Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal

Comment: The number of tiles is determined by the number of threads in the CPU or the amount of GPUs in your system.